# Why docker disk space is growing without control?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

When I boot my `docker-compose up -d` it takes very little disk space.

But during weeks, I am loosing space in my server.

I don't try any other images, so the problem isn't dead containers or images.

Once I boot `docker-compose up -d`, I don't touch that server.

P.D: I know how to free space using `docker system prune` and what I want to know is **why** the space is leaking.

Comment: Have you checked log files? If they're not rotated, they may pile up with time.

Comment: That's exactly what I am testing now. Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have seen a possible solution.

I am trying it now.

Inside the services I have put the following options:

```
myservice:
  logging:
    driver: local
    options:
      max-size: "100m"
```

Perhaps the docker logs are the culprit of the lose of space.

I have seen that the default driver is `json-file`, and it uses more space than `local`.

Also `json-file` has no max size by default.

To be sure I have used `max-size` to limit each log.

Comment: Verified. Seems that now the space is under control with this.